# How can I redirect to a specific page when the database connection fails in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I do not want to see Yii error message when the database connection fails.
How can I redirect to a specific page when the database connection fails with Yii framework?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To catch **all** CDbConnection errors you need to enable an error handler in config/main.php

```
'components'=>array('errorHandler'=>array('errorAction'=>'site/error', ), ),
```

Then, within your controller (or an abstract base class for all your controllers) you need define an action to accomplish the redirect.

```
public function actionError() {
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        if ( CDbException == $error->type) {
           $this->redirect(array("site/error_message")); }
    //  call the parent error handler, but something doesn't feel right about this:
    else
        parent::actionError(); }
```

Alternatively you can just render your custom views:

```
public function actionError() {
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        if ( CDbException == $error->type) {
           $this->render('error', $error); } }
```

See [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action) for more details.

Comment: why not just simplify to: if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error && CDbException == $error->type){...}???

Comment: @Fydo: yea that should work the same. But I prefer pythonic PHP ;) (explicit, readable, significant indentation, etc)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
try { 
    $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $this->redirect(array('controller/action'));
}
```

you can also pass additional info with the redirect, see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail).